# colored text format for readme or simple documentation files

Tags: file-format, text

I am looking for a colored format that is supported by ubuntu to write documentation files that can be displayed colored and bolded to be displayed on a text editor like gedit. I wanted to ask it before getting to start to create my own format. Does anyone know such a format?

Comment: Could you be a li'l more specific? Coloured format documentation for viewing as a webpage, on the terminal or when you open the help menu that opens the documentation?

Comment: yep, you are right I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

README files should be as easy to read as possible without installing additional tools. Therefore, create a simple text README file, and if you want to go fancy, make a README.html version with colors, bells and whistles.

Answer (score 0):

I guess README files should be plain text, so they can easily be opened and read by anyone. But you might use capital letters, special characters to create the formatting effect.